# What's the equivalent of 'COLLATE' in Azure DocumentDb?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to figure out a way to do a case insensitive query on Azure DcoumentDb.
In SQL there is 'COLLATE' which can accomplish this.

Azure DocumentDb does a case sensitive search.

So what's the equivalent of 'COLLATE' here?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Codehelp, there is no equivalent to COLLATE in DocumentDB - only UTF8 string comparison is allowed. This is certainly something for us to consider - please vote this up at http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb.

PS: you can contact me at arramac at Microsoft dot com in case you'd like to discuss in more detail.

Comment: Thanks Aravind. Will get in touch.